# Avoid reshuffling when using state or timers?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I find myself in situations writing Beam pipelines where I want to use state or timers, where the data may already be sharded a certain way by a previous `GroupByKey` which I do not want to disturb. But the API says state or timers requires `KV` inputs to the `PTransform`. Perhaps stateful/timerful transforms do a `GroupByKey` internally.

Is there a way to use state/timers without resharding/reshuffling?

Here is a concrete use case: I am running into a performance problem when implementing my own metrics collection instead of using the beam built-in Stackdriver metrics, where the system lag of transforms involving shuffling starts shooting up and in general does not recover after some time.

Here is the relevant code where I funnel into one key the metric values from various places where the data is potentially sharded differently, simply because I needed to use timers.

```
    metricsFromVariousPlaces
      .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
      .apply(WithKeys.of(null.asInstanceOf[Void]))
      .apply("write influx points",
             new InfluxSinkTransform(...)
```

`InfluxSinkTransform` requires timers in order to flush writes to InfluxDB in a timely fashion.

I understand this causes reshuffling because now the data is all under one shard. I expect this reshuffling to be expensive and hope to avoid it if possible.

I tried preserving the keys from the previous transform, but looks like there is still shuffling:

```
  "stage_id": "S68",
  "stage_name": "F503",
  "fused_steps": [
...
    {
      "name": "s29.org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<init>:402#b70c45c110743c2b-write-streaming-shuffle430",
      "originalTransform": "snapshot/MapElements/Map.out0",
      "userName": "snapshot/MapElements/Map.out0/FromValue/WriteStream"
    }
  ]
...
{
  "stage_id": "S74",
  "stage_name": "F509",
  "fused_steps": [
    {
      "name": "s29.org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<init>:402#b70c45c110743c2b-read-streaming-shuffle431",
      "originalTransform": "snapshot/MapElements/Map.out0",
      "userName": "snapshot/MapElements/Map.out0/FromValue/ReadStream"
    },
    {
      "name": "s30",
      "originalTransform": "snapshot/write influx points/ParDo(Do)",
      "userName": "snapshot/write influx points/ParDo(Do)"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Is your goal for InfluxSink primarily to reduce the number of write calls being made by creating micro batches of BatchOf<logElement> ?

Comment: Hi Reza, not sure what you mean by my goal for InfluxSink? Relative to what?

If I simply perform the influx writing as a side effect of the transforms doing the main pipeline logic then we would be writing duplicate metrics if the bundle were to retry. That's why I am making them go through the pipeline and gather them at InfluxSink before doing the writing to influx in a @FinishBundle callback

Comment: A possible solution might be to use as key instead of `Void` a wrapper element which defers to the coder of the wrapped element, so that it will have the same encoding. But does this ensure that the data won't be reshuffled? (same encoding but of different types... depending on the implementation they might be allocated to different shards?)

Comment: Thanx I understand.. Have you tried creating a key based on a hash which will partition the work into n keys. This will still shuffle of course but the performance might be acceptable. 
Another option is to not use the State API, but to just use a local List<> which you create in the StartBundle and then make use of in the FinishBundle. Ensure you null the list in StartBundle, as DoFn's can be reused. 
BTW I think there is still chance of duplicates, for example if your code runs ok but their is a failure before the FinishBundle code completes... Do you have an option for a Guid?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I already don't use the state API. Only the timer to set a max time before points are flushed to influx. I will try the partitioning into N keys.

Comment: Duplicates have so far not been too much of an issue. It is the entire bundle fused across transforms which is retried right? But because I use timers in the influx sink transform there is a shuffle step after the transforms producing the metrics and right before the influx sink transform. So the potential for duplicates if I understand it correctly comes only from failures in the influx sink transform processing/writing?

Comment: Sorry I end up calling state + timers , state API a bad habit. Timers are per key so if you use state or timers it will shuffle. The List<> solution described  would not cause a shuffle.  
Yes as long as the transform that you use after the shuffle step is deterministic in the creation of the call to the influxDB then you could get those same values duplicated as the whole fused step is retried.

Comment: Hi Reza, the N keys seemed to help (though I needed other performance optimisations thrown in as well) but I couldn't really anticipate how adjusting N would impact performance. Where can I read up more on how reshuffling between two steps can be affected by the difference in the number of keys between the first step and the second? I have different jobs corresponding to different instances the pipeline with different loads also and it is a little disappointing that I have now this additional parameter I have to tweak in addition to the number of workers for a specific instance of a pipeline.

Comment: In general I would go with a hi number of N (00's or 000's) and let the runner take care of the distribution. Allowing it to autoscale up / down. 
However did you try out the List<> as a DoFn object approach? This would avoid the shuffle completely.

Comment: I am sorry but I must have misunderstood you? I am not using state (since I am using a list member of the DoFn object instead) but I am using timers, and from the output of `gcloud dataflow jobs describe --full $JOB_ID --format json` it does seem that shuffling was going on.

Unfortunately we cannot rely on autoscaling yet as the SolaceIO source is not ready for autoscaling.

Comment: Using Timers will cause shuffle as well, Timers are per key and any per key operation will necessitate a shuffle.

Comment: Yes I am aware but I as mentioned, need to use timers to flush points to influx in a timely fashion.

Comment: Right, might be worth exploring using List<> + finishBundle without the timer to see if it suits your use case. In stream mode the bundles tend to be small so would fire often...

Comment: Ah ok I'll try that thanks. But that does worry me as https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/ says that bundle sizes are runner-dependent, and I am not entirely clear how they relate to windows and triggers.

Comment: I ended up implementing application-logic level aggregation of points being written to influx, and since that drastically reduced the data rate after the Combine.perKey we stopped seeing system lag and influx http request timeouts

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use state or timers without inducing shuffling, even when the keys stay unchanged.